# Basic Caesar Cipher Code

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

Could I have a couple people look over my code for a general readability check?  Just make sure it is following Python standards.

```
def casear_cipher(letter, num):
    """ This function acts like a Casear Cipher. 

    Replaces an input letter with another letter a fixed

    number of spaces farther down the alphabet

    Args:

    * letter (string) - any upper case or lower case letter

    * num (integer) - any integer value to shift to a new letter
        """

    #Range 65 to 91 is ASCii values for uppercase alphabet
    if ord(letter) in range (65, 91):  
        x = ord(letter) - ord('A') 
        num_mod_26 = (x + num) % 26
        final_output = chr(ord('A') + num_mod_26)
        return final_output


    #Range 97 to 123 is ASCii values for lowercase alphabet 
    elif ord(letter) in range (97, 123):  
        x = ord(letter) - ord('a') 
        num_mod_26 = (x + num) % 26
        final_output = chr(ord('a') + num_mod_26)
        return final_output
```

Answer (score 11):

First of all welcome to Codereview.

## Good

- You have a decent function.
- You even have a nice docstring to describe what it does!
- You have decent descriptive names.

Overall your code is good, well done!

## Improvements

- Make the `starting_ascii` value more generic, no more duplicated code.
- Rais an appropriate exeption if no letter is given, you might want to handle that differently.

---

## Revised code

```
def casear_cipher(letter, num):
    """This function acts like a Casear Cipher. 

    Replaces an input letter with another letter a fixed
    number of spaces farther down the alphabet

    Args:
    * letter (string) - any upper case or lower case letter
    * num (integer) - any integer value to shift to a new letter"""

    if letter.isupper():
        starting_ascii = ord('A')
    elif letter.islower():
        starting_ascii = ord('a')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Input is not a letter')

    alpha_index = ord(letter) - starting_ascii
    mod_26 = (alpha_index + num) % 26
    return chr(starting_ascii + mod_26)
```

Comment: Minor point. I think the docstring should mention how the function behaves for invalid inputs, i.e. raises an error.

Answer (score 2):

This improvement is not related with readability, but I'm posting it because it can improve the encoding throughput for large text inputs.

Modulus operations are expensive for most integral values, because they require using more expensive instructions such as integer divisions or multiplications.

You can avoid this by just having your alphabet duplicated. The trick is that instead of wrapping the index you just unwrap the alphabet, since the range of a sum of two `0..26` values is always going to be less than `2*26`. It would be a bit trickier but still possible, to support upper and lower case characters.

Here's a simplified code that could complement @Ludisposed answer:

```
from array import array
chars = range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)
chars.extend(chars)
alphabet = array('c',(chr(c) for c in chars))

def caesar_cipher(letter, num):
   return alphabet[ord(letter)-ord('a')+num]

print(alphabet)
hello_encoded = "".join(caesar_cipher(c, 5) for c in "helloworld")
print(hello_encoded)
```

Result:

```
array('c', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
mjqqtbtwqi
```

Comment: I think by avoiding to use the modulus operand, you make it progressively difficult for yourself. Much more then need be.

Comment: You can use the modulus operand for sure, but if you plan to use it once for each character in a 10k character file, then you should think what matters more to you, your processing time or your debugging time. My main language is C, so you can imagine the source of my obsession for this kind of micro-optimizations :)

Comment: That I do understand, but now you've created a whole new set of problems. What happens if a number is largen then 26? How will you handle lowercase and uppercase? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: I hope OP will not encode any data with this cypher, since Ceasar is a toy-grade Cypher. And unsuitable for actually encrypting data. :)

Comment: You can always raise an error or return a placeholder character as invalid, in the same sense you see `?` like characters when your text editor font does not have an specific symbol. Checking for ranges is just a substraction and is real fast. Divisions though, are another story. You can try it yourself and see how this kind of tricks are commonly used in encoding libraries.

Comment: And Donald Knuth's quote is usually misused. If you read the whole quote, he's actually talking about micro-optimizations in non critical code.

Comment: Another optimised way would be to calculate the modulus once, store them in a dictionary and change the text accordingly with O(1) lookup.

Comment: Well a lookup table (what you actually meant, not a dictionary) is precisely what you can see in the array alphabet. It's just a few steps ahead, where you even avoid the conversion to character, but the idea is exactly that. Calculating the modulus is basically iterating from 0 to N-1 and start again.

Comment: This approach can simply be implemented with `str.translate()`, which can also handle non alphabetical characters by either leaving them untouched or removing them.

Comment: @JorgeBellón a lookup table in Python **is** a `dictionary`.

Comment: Python dictionaries use maps (trees) or hashmaps (arrays with lists). Lookup tables are flat (arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Very minor detail: your method name is spelled wrong. It's caesar, not cesaer, after the Roman general and politician who was one of the first recorded users of the cipher. You spelled it right in your question title, but not in your actual code. It's a small detail, but if the method is intended for consumption through an API or in other parts of your code, you may want to make sure that you don't have silly typographical mistakes like this, because fixing them is definitely not trivial, especially on products which have been released.